# Visualizing gluing of polygonal presentation of $T^2 \# T^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to visualize gluing together the polygonal presentation of $T^2 \# T^2$
$$
\langle \alpha_1, \beta_1, \alpha_2, \beta_2 \mid \alpha_1 \beta_1 \alpha_1^{-1} \beta_1^{-1} \alpha_2 \beta_2 \alpha_2^{-1} \beta_2^{-1} \rangle
$$
My understanding is that the presentation is, visually,

[image: unfolded]

When I try to visualize gluing this together, in particular folding the bottom left horizontal line underneath to join with the upper left horizontal, and folding the upper right horizontal over to the bottom right horizontal, I get the following:

[image: semifolded]

Now in the middle there are unjoined two paths, an *upper* one consisting of the vertical (upwards) foreground path and the foreground arc, and a *lower* one consisting of a vertical (downwards) foreground path and a background arc. The ellipse on the right needs to be folded to match the *upper* path, and the ellipse on the left needs to be folded to match the *lower* path. But in each case, one of the segments to be glued is a connected path and the other is unconnected. My visualization winds up with two tori connected by a singular point, rather than glued on an open disc. What am I missing? Is my initial drawing of the presentation wrong; is my gluing so far wrong; or is everything actually okay through this point and my visualization is failing me?

EDIT: Following @Kevin.S 's suggestion, I cut apart the two halves and visualized gluing them in the following steps:

[image]

Step (a) is the same as my final step before; in step (b) I've cut the two halves apart and used a dotted line to mark where they are joined.

In step (c) I visualize pulling on these dotted segments and pinching each together so that one face of each half forms a figure-8; some very fine dotted lines indicate warping of two cylinders due to the pinching. The pinch is valid because when the segments marked with arrows are glued together, these two points will be glued together anyways (I'm jumping the gun a bit for visualization). I've left off step (d), where $T^2 \# T^2$ is finally formed, but just because it's a bit obvious at this point and I have limited tikz skills. Each half will form a torus with an open disc hole, which are re-glued back together in the end.

Comment: Imagine if you cut the cylindrical space into two pieces along the line where they're joined, you'll find each of them is homeomorphic to a torus with hole. That hole is where two tori are supposed to be connected.

Comment: @Kevin.S Thanks for that suggestion! I've edited the question with some visualizations of the next steps along these lines, and (if I've done those correctly) I see how it works now

Comment: I also see now that the cutting line you suggested is homotopic to the open disc at which the tori are glued together, which explains why in my text (Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds) the author states that this disc is homotopic to "either $\alpha_1 \beta_1 \alpha_1^{-1} \beta_1^{-1}$ or $\beta_2 \alpha_2 \beta_2^{-1} \alpha_2^{-1}$", which is what I was trying to understand in the first place. So, if you made an answer, I'd give it a vote.

Comment: Actually, if you already figured that out yourself, you may write an answer to your own question.